# which is best web server for java spring hibernate website

Tags: java, spring, webserver

I have vps and i want to test the website using java spring hibernate mysql.

which is the best web server to install on linux server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a web server to test - Tomcat and Jetty both have HTTP servers built in that are perfectly adequate.  You don't need IIS or Apache web servers, but you do need a servlet/JSP engine and JVM installed.

You don't say if your MySQL database is installed on a server that's separate from the servlet/JSP engine.  I would recommend that you arrange things that way.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring tc server](http://www.springsource.com/products/tcserver) is a good option. It's based on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Appache Tomcat, its lightweight and good for testing. If you would need to deploy EARs or need more J2EE functionality I would suggest Glassfish.

Comment: I am using spring  mvc. I have mysql installed. Can I install glass fish. I have php running on 80 with live sites

Comment: yes you can, it shoudn be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Java is that your application can be relatively context-agnostic, so you should be able to use any generic server and have no problem later installing on a different one. As mentioned elsewhere, Tomcat is a very popular one.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "Servlet container" instead of WebServer because Webserver only deals with Static data but servlet container also deals with dynamic content as well. Like Apache Tomcat.

Tomcat is mature, well-documented, and the most widely used Java application server. With good documentation and no shortage of tutorials about it on the internet, Tomcat is a serious contender for the role of application server in almost all Java web applications.

If we talk about application server, GlassFish is more than just a generic Java EE application server. It’s the reference implementation of the Java EE standard. This means that GlassFish is used to showcase Java EE capabilities, and it gets contributions from the same people who define Java EE standards. Therefore, GlassFish will always support the latest Java EE features first. That’s a plus.